# IIS7 rewrite http and http://www to https

Tags: iis, iis-7, url-rewriting

I switched my application to https. I added system.webServer rewrite rule

```
<rule name="HTTP to HTTPS redirect" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="(.*)" />
    <conditions>
      <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" ignoreCase="true" />
    </conditions>
  <action type="Redirect" redirectType="Found" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" />
</rule>
```

in my web.config

It rewrites `http://mydomain.com` to `https://mydomain.com` which is good.
Bot how to make it to rewrite also `http://www.mydomain.com` to `https://mydomain.com` (without www)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You could make a separate rule that changes the www.mydomain.com into mydomain.com
2. You could just hardcode your http_host and instead of using {HTTP_HOST} simply put there: "mydomain.com" so

   <action type="Redirect" redirectType="Found" url="https://mydomain.com/{R:1}" />

Comment: Any link to rewrite rules documentation?

Comment: Why don't you create them not in web.config - but straight from IIS7's URL Rewrite Module's front end? it's far easier.. as to documentation google-> "iis url rewrite" ..

Comment: I tried 2. way and it works. Documentation http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/465/url-rewrite-module-configuration-reference