# Force Https on an ASP.NET app running on IIS 7.5

Tags: asp.net, regex, iis, iis-7, https

I am forcing SSL on my entire site with the following code on my web.config file;

```
<system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
        <rules>
            <rule name="Redirect HTTP to HTTPS" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="(.*)"/>
                <conditions>
                    <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^OFF$"/>
                </conditions>
                <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" redirectType="SeeOther"/>
            </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
</system.webServer>
```

but what I would like to do is to force ssl only the `~/purchase/` and `~/account/` path and under them. what should be the match url for that?

**NOTE** Regular Expressions also would work for me here as well as wildcard.

Comment: oh, god. It is enough here at stackoverflow.com. how is this topic could be *off topic*? If somebody vote to close this as off topic question, then s/he has no idea on programming. And if you vote to close, then please have enough respect to leave a comment explaining why!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use this pattern (this will work for `/purchase/something` as well as `/account/something-else`):

```
^((purchase|account)/.*)$
```

You have to remember, that URL should have no leading slash `/`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="Force HTTPS" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="^((purchase|account)/.*)$" />
                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^OFF$" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" redirectType="Permanent" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: @tugberk Sorry, I do not understand your question.The Final URL will be the same as original just HTTPS protocol instead of HTTP. The rule will ONLY be triggered for URLs with `purchase/` or `account/` part present.

Comment: ahh ok. the question that I asked as comment was stupid. ignore it. I will give it a try.

Comment: @LazyOne, What is the Difference between <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^OFF$" /> and <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" /> ?

Comment: @cracker `^off$` is an **exact match** in regex while `off` means just that sequence **anywhere** in the string. But yes -- considering that `HTTPS` field should only have `ON` and `OFF` as values, the difference is non existent.

Comment: @LazyOne, Thanks Buddy Now I got his. Can you suggest if I want to add HTTP for other Link then www.mysite.com/purchase/login the Word containing other then Purchase in URL for all Link and Navigations. How can I do that?

Comment: @cracker I'm not sure that I have understood you correctly .. but if you want to add some another word (in addition to already defined `purchase` and `account` -- as described in the Answer), just list it with `|`, e.g. `purchase|account|checkout` -- this will not cover `/checkout/some-url` as well.

Comment: @LazyOne I want to use SSL for all the pages other then purchase|account

Comment: @cracker *"other then purchase|account*" -- that does not make sense to me -- why would you have most important pages without https protection and protect other (product details, help page) pages. Anyway: if you want to force HTTPS for all pages -- look at http://stackoverflow.com/q/6358996/783119 and similar. Otherwise -- create your own question with your specific requirements.

Answer (score 0):

you would do something like this (2 separate rules for simplicity)

```
  <match url="/purchase/(.*)"/>
```

Comment: can we it like that : `<match url="/purchase|account/(.*)"/>`

Comment: we can do this : `<match url="/purchase|account/(.*)"/>` but what would be the redirect url would look like ? `url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}"`

Comment: ok, for this : `<match url="/account/(.*)"/>` tried the following redirect url but didn't work; `url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/account/{R:1}"`